# How can I get elements in jQuery starting with a particular pattern and ending with another pattern

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="Tab1">
    <input type="text" id="ctl100_Tab1_one_text"/>
    <input type="text" id="ctl100_Tab1_two_text"/>

</div>
<div id="Tab2">
    <input type="text" id="ctl100_Tab2_one_text"/>
    <input type="text" id="ctl100_Tab2_two_text"/>

</div>
```

I want all textboxes under Tab1 separate to Tab2

Comment: show us a dom example. you question is very unclear.

Comment: How do you "want" them? Do you mean you want references to them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the code you posted:

```
<div id="Tab1">
    <input type="text" id="ctl100_Tab1_one_text"/>
    <input type="text" id="ctl100_Tab1_two_text"/>

</div>
<div id="Tab2">
    <input type="text" id="ctl100_Tab2_one_text"/>
    <input type="text" id="ctl100_Tab2_two_text"/>

</div>
```

And the question:

> I want all textboxes under Tab1 separate to Tab2

```
$('#tab1 input:text')
```

However, given the title of your question:

> How can I get elements in jQuery starting with a particular pattern and ending with another pattern?

You could use:

```
$('input:text[id^=startsWithPattern][id$=endsWithPattern]');
```

Using the [`^=` (attribute-starts-with selector)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), and [`$=` (attribute-ends-with selector)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

As demonstrated with a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aJUPx/1/).

Answer (score 1):

To get all input types under tab1 use this selector:

```
$('#Tab1 input');
```